# LINQ Conditional Group

Tags: linq, grouping

Is it possible to write a LINQ statement with a conditional group clause?  Here is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
bool someFlag = false;

var result = from t in tableName
   group t by new { (someFlag ? 0 : t.FieldA), t.FieldB } into g
   select g;
```

So basically if someFlag is set to true, I want to group only by FieldB, but if it's false I want to group by FieldA and FieldB.

Comment: Are FieldA and FieldB of the same type? If so, that can greatly simplify things.

Comment: Also, I assume that someFlag is dependent on the current element?

Comment: Yeah, FieldA and FieldB are both integers.  And someFlag would be passed in as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Co-worker figured it out for me:

```
bool someFlag = false;
var result = from t in tableName
   group t by new { FieldA = (someFlag ? 0 : t.FieldA), t.FieldB } into g
   select g;
```

Comment: You can leave off everything after the "}". You don't explicitly have to select grouped items.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that your `someFlag` is not a variable dependent on the current element of the iterator, then I think you could make your code more readable by writing the following.

```
bool someFlag = false;
var result = someFlag ?
     (from t in tableName group t by t.FieldA into g select g) :
     (from t in tableName group t by t.FieldB into g select g);
```

Admittedly it's slightly longer, but its purpose is significantly more obvious in my opinion.

And to slightly simplify the code you just posted:

```
bool someFlag = false;
var result = from t in tableName
   group t by (someFlag ? t.FieldA : t.FieldB) into g
   select g;
```

...or am I missing something here?