# How to create LINQ to SQL Group by with condition?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How can I create LINQ to SQL request where I can use group by with condition?

For example:

```
    from ri in resItems
    group ri by new {groupByPackaging ? (ri.Model, ri.Condition, ri.Packaging) : (ri.Model, ri.Condition)}
    into g
        select new
        {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for [LINQ Conditional Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756827/linq-conditional-group)

Here's an example:

```
bool someFlag = false;
var result = from t in tableName
      group t by new { FieldA = (someFlag ? 0 : t.FieldA), t.FieldB } into g
      select g;
```