# GroupBy on Multiple Properties Based on Parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table full of addresses.  My goal is to find people who have similar addresses, and group them together.  I can, of course, do :

```
var groups = addresses.GroupBy(a => a.FullAddress);
```

which is fine.  But the user is offered the option to select the address properties they want to be applied in the GroupBy.  For Example:

```
//user selected postalCode & state
var groups = addresses.GroupBy(a => new { a.PostalCode, a.State });
```

There are 6 booleans that the user can incorporate into their search in total.  Is there a simple way via LINQ to approach this problem?  I'm sure I can hammer out some if statements if not, but I imagined there was a more elegant solution, and I was unable to find any similar questions.

This is in an ASP.NET MVC project, as part of a service that builds up an `AddressGroupsViewModel` using the Entity Framework for a reporting page.

```
public AddressGroupsViewModel GetSearchResults(bool address1, bool address2, bool city, bool state, bool country, bool postalcode)
{

}
```

**SOLUTION**

Given the accepted answer (which was nearly what I needed), I created this query that satisfies my requirements :

```
var groups = dbContext
               .GroupBy(t => new
                    {
                        Address1 = (address1 ? t.AddressLine1 : ""),
                        Address2 = (address2 ? t.AddressLine2 : ""),
                        City = (city ? t.City : ""),
                        State = (state ? t.State : ""),
                        Country = (country ? t.Country : ""),
                        PostalCode = (postalcode ? t.PostalCode : "")
                    });
```

Comment: Can you provide your method signature? What do you return?

Comment: Have you seen this post on conditional grouping in LINQ [LINQ Conditional Group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756827/linq-conditional-group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public AddressGroupsViewModel GetSearchResults(bool address1, bool address2, bool city, bool state, bool country, bool postalcode)
{
   var result = from t in tableName
   group t by new { 
      FieldA = (address1 ? "" : t.Address1),
      FieldB = (address2 ? "" : t.Address2),
      FieldC = (city ? "" : t.City),
      FieldD = (state ? "" : t.State),
      FieldE = (country ? "" : t.Country),
      FieldF = (postalcode ? "" : t.PostalCode)
   } into g
   select g;
   ......
}
```