# How to group a list of data into year, season, month, week, day?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am dealing with big data of years.

The data model is quite simple:

```
public class ValueData
{
    public DateTime TimeRecorded {get; set;}
    public double   ValueRecorded {get; set;}
}
```

After having a list of ValueData: `List<ValueData>` for years of data, I need to group the data based on: Year ==> contains data of 4 seasons: Season ==> A season contains 4 months ==> A month contains data of 4 weeks ==> A week contains data of 7 days based on the week calendar numbers of a year. Because I need to make a sum of data per year, per season, per month, per week and per day

How can I achieve this data classification? should I use LinQ?

Comment: You can use LINQ and you can use a different approach. However, where did you get stuck? This sounds like a requirement specification.

Comment: how many records are we talking about?

Comment: @TimSchmelter im stucking to find a way to group data based on year, season, month, week and day. Which is another approach that you can think of?

Comment: @Marcom it is about 2 GB data

Comment: Are you after something like  `var grp = dataList.GroupBy(d => new
{
                Year=d.TimeRecorded.Year, Month=d.TimeRecorded.Month, }).ToList();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like  [conditional groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756827/linq-conditional-group)
but 2gbs of data will take a while to process. 
I guess it's ok for a one time parse and save the results but if you need to run this often you'll need a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something along the lines of the following query:

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(v => new {Year = v.TimeRecorded.Year,
                                    Season = SeasonFromMonth(v.TimeRecorded.Month),
                                    Month = v.TimeRecorded.Month,
                                    Week = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(v.TimeRecorded, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, System.DayOfWeek.Monday),
                                    Day = v.TimeRecorded.Day});
```

With a helper function `SeasonFromMonth` that accepts the integer month and returns some value (probably an enum) indicating the season.

You can then select relevant subgroups with queries like:

```
var fallValues = groups.Where(g => g.Key.Season == Seasons.Fall);
var decemberValues = groups.Where(g => g.Key.Month == 12);
var firstOfMonth = groups.Where(g => g.Key.Day == 1);
```

and so on, or flatten the groups into a single list by adding a `SelectMany` clause (although the `SelectMany` will throw away the key information):

```
groups.Where(g => g.Key.Season == Seasons.Fall).SelectMany(g => g);
groups.Where(g => g.Key.Month == 12).SelectMany(g => g);
groups.Where(g => g.Key.Day == 1).SelectMany(g => g);
```